# Sort table rows based on their Class Names

Tags: jquery

I want to rearrange table rows based on their Class names.
Below is my HTML code.

```
<table>
 <tr class="a4"><td>4</td></tr>
 <tr class="a6"><td>6</td></tr>
 <tr class="a1"><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr class="a2"><td>2</td></tr>
 <tr class="a5"><td>5</td></tr>
 <tr class="a3"><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

So now,  with class name a1 should display first, likewise a2 second.. etc..

Please someone help me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on an external plugin, you can extract the numbers from the class names using [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and sort the elements using the built-in [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/sort) method.

From there, you can use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to reorder the table rows (it will remove each row from the table then re-add it at the proper position):

```
$("table").append($("tr").get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($(a).attr("class").match(/\d+/), 10)
         - parseInt($(b).attr("class").match(/\d+/), 10);
}));
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFDWN/).

Comment: since .attr deprecated, It should be: return parseInt($(a).prop("class").match(/\d+/)) - parseInt($(b).prop("class").match(/\d+/))

Answer (score 3):

You could use [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/) plugin and to something like:

```
jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function(){

    var sort = [].sort;

    return function(comparator, getSortable) {

        getSortable = getSortable || function(){return this;};

        var placements = this.map(function(){

            var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
                parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,

                // Since the element itself will change position, we have
                // to have some way of storing its original position in
                // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
                nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
                    document.createTextNode(''),
                    sortElement.nextSibling
                );

            return function() {

                if (parentNode === this) {
                    throw new Error(
                        "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
                    );
                }

                // Insert before flag:
                parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
                // Remove flag:
                parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);

            };

        });

        return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i){
            placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
        });

    };

})();
// do the sorting
$('tr').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return $(a).attr('class') > $(b).attr('class') ? 1 : -1;
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZV5yc/1/

Comment: i think this is much better to have higher up rating thanks.