# Order divs by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to order divs by class when clicking a menu link?
Here is my code:

```
<ul class="directors-menu">
    <li>director1</li>
    <li>director2</li>
    <li>director3</li>
    <li>commercial</li>
    <li>promo</li>
    <li>short</li>
</ul>
<div class="films">
    <div class="director1 commercial"></div>
    <div class="director1 promo"></div>
    <div class="director2 commercial"></div>
    <div class="director2 short"></div>
    <div class="director3 commercial"></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is when I click on a director or category in the menu I would like the divs with the connected class to be ordered at the top.

Here is an example: When I click on director2 in the menu I would like the code to change to this:

```
<ul class="directors-menu">
    <li>director1</li>
    <li>director2</li>
    <li>director3</li>
    <li>commercial</li>
    <li>promo</li>
    <li>short</li>
</ul>
<div class="films">
    <div class="director2 commercial"></div>
    <div class="director2 short"></div>
    <div class="director1 commercial"></div>
    <div class="director1 promo"></div>
    <div class="director3 commercial"></div>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: You should be happy to have such a solveable problem in hand. Hints: `.text()`, `.hasClass()`, `.prependTo(parent)` :-)

Comment: Possible solution you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730501/sort-table-rows-based-on-their-class-names (with minor adjustments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you fix your HTML to be legal (close your divs), you can use this:

```
$(".directors-menu li").click(function() {
    var cls = $(this).text();
    var films = $(".films");
    films.find("." + cls).each(function() {
        films.prepend(this);
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/43muT/

And, a bit shorter version:

```
$(".directors-menu li").click(function() {
    var films = $(".films");
    films.find("." + $(this).text()).prependTo(films);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/nLV2j/

---

It would better to put a custom attribute on the clickable items so the display text can be anything and you have direct control over the sort key like this:

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="directors-menu">
    <li data-sort="director1">Sort by Director 1</li>
    <li data-sort="director2">Sort by director 2</li>
    <li data-sort="director3">Sort by director 3</li>
    <li data-sort="commercial">commercial</li>
    <li data-sort="promo">promo</li>
    <li data-sort="short">short</li>
</ul>
<div class="films">
    <div class="director2 commercial">d2</div>
    <div class="director2 short">d2</div>
    <div class="director1 commercial">d1</div>
    <div class="director1 promo">d1</div>
    <div class="director3 commercial">d3</div>
</div>
```

And, the code:

```
$(".directors-menu li").click(function() {
    var films = $(".films");
    films.find("." + $(this).data("sort")).prependTo(films);
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GZhtr/

Comment: @user1853580 - Added a shorter version.

Comment: Thanks! This made it! but i would like to have a forename and surname on some directors, then this doesn't work. Do you know what can fix this? Here is a fiddle jsfiddle.net/caquA

Comment: @DrMtotheac - you'd have to show the actual HTML you're trying to work with.  It would be best if you put a class or custom attribute on the items you want to click on so the display text can be independent of what you want to sort on.

Comment: @DrMtotheac - I added an example of a better way to do it that allows you to use any display text and control the sort key separtely.

Comment: @DrMtotheac - I've given you an example of the recommended technique (added to the end of my answer) and it looks directly applicable to your HTML.

Comment: It was! I didn't update the page before I wrote the comment. Now it all works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a nice way to do it

```
$(".directors-menu li").click(function(e){
    $("div."+$(this).text()).prependTo("div.films");
});
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Vgt4s/

Answer (score -1):

For sorting anything, the best jQuery plugin I have used is [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)