# Reordering list items with jQuery by extracting their class names

Tags: jquery

I want to rearrange my list order by extracting numbers from the class names using match (I adapted  code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730501/sort-table-rows-based-on-their-class-names)), but it doesn't work. Here are my codes :

HTML :

```
<ul class="class-of-ul">
    <li><a href="#" class="class-of-li-66">66</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="class-of-li-69 current-li">69</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="class-of-li-65" >65</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="class-of-li-68" >68</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="class-of-li-67" >67</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul").append($("li").get().sort(function(a, b) {
        return parseInt($(a).attr("class").match(/\d+/)) - parseInt($(b).attr("class").match(/\d+/))
    }));
});
```

and this is the jsfidle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/d8gfk/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `class` is for the `a` element inside the `li`, so you need to use use `.find()` to get the `anchor` element and find its class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").append($("li").get().sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find('a').attr('class').match(/\d+/) - $(b).find('a').attr('class').match(/\d+/)
    }));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dnL8c/)

Comment: Hi, I have implemented this on my website but unfortunatelly it returns error on console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined. Any idea on this?

Comment: @dreamexploded that means `.attr('class')` is undefined, can you add a `console.log(a, $(a).find('a').attr('class')); console.log(b, $(b).find('a').attr('class'))` and see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

Because you are sorting on `li` elements, but they don't have any classes. The `a` elemnts do. Move your classes to the `li` elements and all will be well.

http://jsfiddle.net/d8gfk/3/

```
<ul class="class-of-ul">
    <li  class="class-of-li-66"><a href="#">66</a></li>
    <li  class="class-of-li-69 current-li"><a href="#">69</a></li>
    <li  class="class-of-li-65" ><a href="#">65</a></li>
    <li  class="class-of-li-68" ><a href="#">68</a></li>
    <li  class="class-of-li-67" ><a href="#">67</a></li>
</ul>
```

Alternately you could inspect the `a` inside each `li` on sort.