# Sorting table rows based on column class names using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-table

Very similair to this question: [Sort table rows based on their Class Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730501/sort-table-rows-based-on-their-class-names) 
Consider the following table:

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <th>A column</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td class="x">A</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="c">B</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="">C</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to sort rows based on the first (in this case only) column class name. Some `td` don't have a class specified. So the desired effect would be: `A-B-C -> C-B-A or B-A-C` (I don't care where the classless tds are placed). I know I can get class with jquery, for example:

```
$(table tr).eq(1).find('td').eq(0).attr('class')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sorting array of `tr` elements. You can get class of element in function of sort and set arrangement of every element.

```js
$("table tbody tr").sort(function (a, b){
    return $("td", b).attr("class") < $("td", a).attr("class") ? 1 : -1;    
}).appendTo('table tbody');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>A column</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="x">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="c">B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">C</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this sort of works. it produces some new rows, is that by any chance because each row has a module in one of the columns? if I call $('table').size() before your function and after, I get two different results.

Comment: @peech I can't see any difference in it. See https://jsfiddle.net/bybgt827/

Comment: hmm. I think the problem is that I have a datepicker in the previously spoken about module. Never mind, I'll look into it myself. Thanks.