# How can I group my data based by status in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[image]I want to sort them based on their status but I don't know how will I proceed so that when i click Active it will show all active data and when inactive it will show all inactive data. I am still in process of learning Javascript.

Here is my code in JS where the buttons are set to active and inactive.

```
$(document).on('click', '.status_checks', function() {
var status = '1';
if ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) {
    status = '0';
}
var id = $(this).data('id');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../forms/form_statusForspecs.php",
    data: {
        id: id,
        status: status
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#dataTables').append(data);
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

});

Here is my code in HTML where I fetch the "status" column in mySQL

```
<td>
   <center>
   <p data-id="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"
    class="status_checks statusButton <?php echo ($row['status'])? 'btn-success': 'btn-danger'?>">
    <?php echo ($row['status'])? 'Active' : 'Inactive'?>
   </p>
   </center>
</td>
```

Here is my code in Selection, I don't have the code for the function for this

```
    <div>
        <form action="GET">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Table group by Status </label>
                <select name="id" style="width:200px;" class="show-menu-arrow form-control" 
                 id="stats" onchange="statusReload(this)" required>
                    <option value="1" selected="">ACTIVE</option>
                    <option value="0">INACTIVE</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: [sorting-table-rows-based-on-column-class-names-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352546/sorting-table-rows-based-on-column-class-names-using-jquery)

Comment: Can you put your code here? https://jsfiddle.net/bybgt827/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the `.status_checks` contains *Active* or *Inactive* using [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and then use `.closest("tr")` to show that particular tr only else hide them.

***Demo code*** :

```js
$("#stats").change(function() {
  //get value from select box and set active or inactive
  var val = $(this).val() == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive"
  console.log(val)
  //hide trs
  $("table tbody tr").hide()
  //find statuscheck tag and check if it contains active/inactive show that tr
  $("table tr").find(".status_checks:contains(" + val + ")").closest("tr").show()

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form action="GET">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Table group by Status </label>
      <select name="id" style="width:200px;" class="show-menu-arrow form-control" id="stats" required>
        <option value="1" selected="">ACTIVE</option>
        <option value="0">INACTIVE</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <p data-id="1" class="status_checks statusButton btn-success">
            Active
          </p>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <p data-id="2" class="status_checks statusButton btn-success">
            Active
          </p>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <p data-id="3" class="status_checks statusButton btn-danger">
            Inactive
          </p>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <p data-id="4" class="status_checks statusButton btn-danger">
            Inactive
          </p>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5
      </td>
      <td>
        <center>
          <p data-id="5" class="status_checks statusButton btn-success">
            Active
          </p>
        </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Also, if you need to show all datas again you can use `$("table tbody tr").show()` .

Comment: What if once I make the data Inactive when I refresh the page the ones that will be left in the table are the active? does it have to do with php? or still js?

Comment: no above code will only get called onchange of select-box  . So, on refresh all datas will show again.