# Sorting table rows based on column class names using pure Javascript

Tags: javascript

Very similar to this question: [Sort table rows based on their Class Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730501/sort-table-rows-based-on-their-class-names) - but need it to be in pure javascript instead of JQuery.

It needs to be able to sort by class names.

Consider the following table:

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <th>Column</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td class="High">High</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="Medium">Medium</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="Low">Low</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The functions need to sort the table by high, medium and low in that particular order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp

Comment: Thank you for replying. Not really as it needs to be in a certain order. I shall rephrase my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

- get the rows of the table body
- sort the array according to the `className` of the first column of each row
- update the `innerHTML` of the table body by joining the `html` content of the resulted sorted list of row elements

```js
const tableBody = document.getElementById("tableBody");
const rows = tableBody.rows;
const weights = {"Low":0, "Medium":1, "High":2};
 
const sortedRows = [...rows].sort((a,b) =>
  weights[a.children[0].className] - weights[b.children[0].className]
);


tableBody.innerHTML =[...sortedRows].map(row => row.outerHTML).join("");
```

```html
<table>
   <thead>
       <th>Column</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="tableBody">
       <tr>
           <td class="High">High</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="Medium">Medium</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td class="Low">Low</td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Is there any way to do this without the tbody? Could i just replace it with the table id, if i don't have a tbody?

Comment: @Matthew98 you are welcome, yes you can set the ``id`` to the ``table`` but in this case it will take the rows of the header as well.